Isomorphism theorem misunderstanding
One of the isomorphism theorems states $(HN) \ / \ N \cong H \ / \ (H\cap N)$.
I am confused about the first part $(HN) \ / \ N$, and whether it is equivalent to $H \ / \ N$. Every element in $HN$ is $hn$ for some $h \in H, n \in N$. So then every coset in $(HN) \ / \ N$ can be expressed as $\{hnN \text{ for some } h \in H, n \in N\}$, but this is just the same as $\{hN \text{ for some } h \in H\}$, so why isn't the first isomorphism theorem just
$H \ / \ N \cong H \ / \ (H\cap N)$

Not sure this is the first isomorphism theorem.

@Kan't It is in some literature.

As far as I could survey so far, I didn't find any, @azif00. Could you share/mention a such one, please?

Abstract Algebra by Blair and Beachy

The notation $A/B$ only makes sense (as a group) when $B$ is a normal subgroup of $A$.
In general, we do not require that $H$ contains $N$ for the theorem holds.
However, the equality $HN/N = \{hN : h \in H\}$ is correct.

I added "(as a group)" because some people study the set of left cosets, denoted by $A/B$, and the notation makes sense as a group when it coincides with right cosets, denoted $B\setminus A$, so when $B\unlhd A$.

@Shaun Yes, I agree.
